# JavaScript import statements changing to require after compilation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, import, gulp, require

I have some JavaScript helper modules I use to access frequently used functions. It usually works fine but lately something weird is happening and I can seem to find a solution. So when I want to import the helper modules I add the following line;

```
import { debounce } from '../../../modules/helper-modules';
```

However, after I save the file and check the page and console I get the following error;

[image]

When I check where the error is coming from the import line from above has been changed to;

```
var _helperModules = require("../../../modules/helper-modules");
```

I can't seem to figure out how this is happening and online resources are non-existent. Has anyone run into this issue before?

I've checked every file connected to my main js file as well as my helper modules.

Comment: Could you edit the question to supply more details of what the build process does, please? I assume you are using gulp to modify the original in some manner.

Comment: I was able to figure out this issue. There was a compileModules setting set to false that should have been set to true. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Great. To indicate the question has been solved you could , if you wish, write up, post and accept the answer you arrived at -  with the kind of technical details  that would have saved you, and potentially future readers with the same problem, a lot of time...